# add data in ontology with owl api using html form in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, owl-api

I am using OWL Api 3.5 in eclipse kepler with a simple ontology in Protege 4. I have uploaded an ontology from local files and add new class "clsN" in it with individual "M2". what I want is to add this class "clsN" and individual "M2" in ontology through HTML form fields. Idon't how to do this.

kindly give me some idea related to this. Here is the my java class code.

```
public class Ontologytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException {

        OWLOntologyManager m = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        File file = new File("C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/test.owl");

        OWLDataFactory f = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();
        OWLOntology o;
        o = m.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
        OWLClass clsN = f.getOWLClass(IRI.create("urn:test#ClassN"));
        OWLDeclarationAxiom declarationAxiom = f.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(clsN);
        m.addAxiom(o, declarationAxiom);
        OWLNamedIndividual M2 = f.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("urn:test" + "#M2"));
        OWLClassAssertionAxiom clsD = f.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(clsN, M2);
        m.addAxiom(o, clsD);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing is

```
m.saveOntology(o);
```

to save the newly added class and individual in your file.

Comment: i used this line in my file, here its just missed out...And how to add classes in the ontology through html forms?

Comment: HTML input is not something that OWLAPI covers. But there's nothing special to it - you could just let the user enter a class name and pass that field across to your Java code.